# batch command to update SharePoint list item using updatelistitems

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, updatelistitems, batch

I am new to SharePoint and i need help to update lookup field, multi line of text field and date field from one list to another list using SharePoint web services updatelistitems.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks
H

Comment: Refer this [link](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.in/2009/01/batch-update-in-sharepoint.html) for updating lookup field.

Comment: @Vishal M. Patil Thanks for replying but what i am looking for is, let's say we have 2 identical lists i.e List A and List B and we selected some value in List A Lookup field and Date & Time Field and save it then it should copy that selected value to List B.

 I tried this (<Field Name=’CustomerID’ Type=’LookUp’  LookUpID=’True’ >1</Field>) and it shows lookup value for ID =1 but not sure how to get values dynamically.

Thanks!!